# How to dynamically set dates from data in d3 calendar view?

Tags: d3.js

In the d3 [calendar view](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063318) example, I am trying to modify it to automatically determine the range of years to display from the data given it.

Is it possible to have d3 automatically figure out what arguments to pass to d3.range() to automatically determine the start and end year, rather than have hard-coded literals?

In the .data() line below, I've tried using d3.min() and d3.max() as arguments to d3.range(), but that's not correct. I've tried sorting the nested data beforehand to obtain the first and last entry in the array, but that has not worked.  Suggestions?

```
    return d3.select( "body" )
             .selectAll( "svg" )
             .data(d3.range(1990, 2010))
             .enter()
             .append( "svg" )
             .attr( "width", width )
             .attr( "height", height )
             .attr( "class", "year" )
             .append( "g" )
             .attr( "transform", "translate(" + getOffsetX() + "," + getOffsetY() + ")" );
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put everything that is done before the `d3.csv("dji.csv",` inside the callback and after the `d3.nest()`, modify the following line

```
var range = d3.extent(csv, d => Number(d.Date.substring(0,4)));
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .selectAll("svg")
  .data(d3.range(range[0], range[1]))
  .enter().append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width - cellSize * 53) / 2) + "," + (height - cellSize * 7 - 1) + ")");
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.  I never would have figured this out on my own.  I added 1 range[1] to include the end year I wanted.

Comment: probably `d3.range()` is **not** inclusive of the last value. I had not constructed a complete example I only tested if the `range` variable was calculated correct. Maybe you can mark it as the selected answer.